# Populating a table on click event

Tags: php, html-table

I have an accordion menu with data brought from database.
The menu is a list or professors and their disciplines.
Besides the slide effect, when I click on professor's name I need to fill a `table` with data from database.
I can get the `id` attribut of that professor and to get the data needed ( Guess the best option is ajax).
But I have no idea how to fill the table with data.

Here is the example: http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/zGQMpw

UPDATE:

I have a table with the days of the week, also a column with the time of discipline. I need to Click on the Professor, get his ID then use this ID to retrieve ALL disciplines from that professor (already doing it and creating a sublist), but I need to insert the right discipline on the right TIME and DAY of the week.

Comment: Do an ajax-call inside of the click-event  $(".prof-list h3").click(function() and fill some element with data returned?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I'll get the attribut of that clicked element, which will be professor's ID. Then I want to use this ID to get data from database and fill the table... Just need some guide of how to do it.

Comment: Whoever gave the downvote, at least comment the reason here... thanks

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro As he said, use AJAX. You need to write Javascript to do this without submitting a form and reloading the page.

Comment: You can use a library like jqGrid or jQuery Datatables.

Comment: @Barmar thanks man, never heard about these two options you showed me. Thanks guys !  Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I would do something like this:

Create an ajax-call and create the table on server-side:

```
<?php
function call_this_function_from_js_with_ajax() {
    //Fetch data from database
    $table_html ="<thead><th>{$title from db}</th></thead>';
    $table_html .= "<tbody>';
    $table_html .= "<tr><td>{$value1 from db}</td></tr>";
    $table_html .= "<tr><td>{$value2 from db}</td></tr>";
    $table_html .= "<tr><td>{$value3 from db}</td></tr>"; //etc etc
    $table_html .= "</tbody>";
   return $table_html;
}
?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".prof-list h3").click(function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle();

     //Do ajax call and put the returned data into the the table
     //
     on success:
     `$("table.col-md-6").html(data);`

})
```

**html**

```
<table class="col-md-6">
{your returned data would be seen here}
</table>
```